# How to completely disable Mac MissionControl

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion, mission-control

As shown in the screenshot I have removed all of the keyboard shortcuts to go into Mission Control. Somehow occasionally it still happens. Problem is it then freezes the MBPro for couple of tens of seconds - i can not have any interaction with the laptop during that time.

I am on 10.8.4

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "it still happens"? Does it just start at random?

Comment: @slhck Well being a software program it is probably not random; however, I have not been able to determine the specific circumstances that trigger the behavior. So it "seems" random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably set to activate with a gesture on a trackpad or mouse. Go into the Mouse and/or trackpad settings in System Preferences, look under More Gestures and disable the ones for Mission Control.

Comment: When I'm reading or thinking, I tend to kind of trail my fingers over the trackpad, which means that several times a day the screen goes into a seizure as my MacBook tries to conjure up the little screens it thinks I want. Gets my vote for Feature that Most Closely Resembles a Bug. Thanks for the cure.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable, and disable Mission Control with the following commands:
(I'm running 10.10.5 Yosemite OSX)

Enable:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock mcx-expose-disabled && killall Dock
```

Disable:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock mcx-expose-disabled -bool TRUE && killall Dock
```

Comment: This does nothing - the F3 still launches Mission control